# How to override NULL value from aggregate query using MySQLdb module in python?

Tags: python, mysql

I am selecting the maximum date value from a MySQL database table in python using the MySQLdb module. If the result comes back as null, I want to override it with a default value. I could do this in the MySQL using a sub-query, but would prefer to do it in python.

Any recommendations on a simple way to do this? I figure this is an easy one, but I'm new to python so I thought it was worth asking.

Here's my code so far:

```
db=MySQLdb.connect(...)
cur = db.cursor()
cur.execute("select max(date_val) from my_table;")
min_date = cur.fetchone()[0]
```

Thanks in advance!

**Edit:**
"print min_date" outputs "None" if the value is null. I want to override it with a default value, such as "2010-01-01".

Comment: When you print `mid_date` what do yousee?  What do you want it to be? Please don't comment.  Please update your question with the additional details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
min_date = cur.fetchone()[0]
min_date = min_date if min_date is not None else default_value
```

Answer (score 4):

> I could do this in the MySQL using a sub-query, but would prefer to do it in python.

Why do you say you need a subquery? You can just use [COALESCE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce):

```
"select COALESCE(max(date_val), 'your_default_value_here') from my_table;"
```

Comment: You are correct. This is a good way to do it, but I'm glad to know how to do it in python now too. Thanks!