# Is there a simple way to suppress WTForms form field default values?

Tags: wtforms

Whenever I use a WTForms form to display data from a database:

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM rolodex WHERE rolodex_id = " + rolodex_id
cursor = mdb_connect("DictCursor")
cursor.execute(sql)
row = cursor.fetchone()
form = RolodexEntry(**row)
return bottle.template('entry',rolodex_id=rolodex_id,form=form)
```

(all form fields are TextFields)

empty and NULL database field values are displayed as "None".  I want them to just be empty.  I can think of a couple of ways to solve this problem, but am wondering if there is some WTForms-approved way to set the default value of a Textfield to be the empty string rather than None?

Bottle templates give me a simple if somewhat tedious way of solving this problem on a case by case basis:

```
<p style='font-weight: bold; color: blue; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; width:   50%'>
% if form.firstname.data:
  {{form.firstname.data}} 
% end 
% if form.lastname.data:
  {{form.lastname.data}}
% end
</p>
```

I tried changing the default attribute in the field definition:

```
firstname  = TextField('First Name',[validators.length(max=40)], default="")
```

but this didn't do anything; i.e. form.firstname.data still displays as `None` if the field is empty in the database.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was being caused by the strip_filter filter I was using with all Textfields:

```
strip_filter = lambda x: x.strip() if x else None
```

as in

```
cell = TextField('Cellphone', [validators.length(max=25)],
                 filters=[strip_filter])
```

Changing the strip filter to:

```
strip_filter = lambda x: x.strip() if x else ""
```

resolved this issue.

The problem was compounded by the fact that the WTForms `default` field attribute seems not to work.  Using this field definition:

```
cell = TextField('Cellphone', default = "Nada")
```

and this code:

```
row['cell'] = ""
form = RolodexEntry(**row)
return bottle.template('entry',rolodex_id=rolodex_id,form=form)
```

The HTML for `<td>{{form.cell.data}}</td>` gives `<td></td>`, not `<td>Nada</td>`

Comment: On further experimentation, it's now clear that the WTForms default field attribute is only used if the field is missing entirely.  In particular, in the preceding code example, replace `row['cell'] = ""` with `del row['cell']` and the default value Nada will kick in for `form.cell.data`

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid I can't think of WTForms-approved way to set default values as anything passed to default will be, well..default. So if we target this at the database select level you could use something like this question;

[How to override NULL value from aggregate query using MySQLdb module in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2321518/how-to-override-null-value-from-aggregate-query-using-mysqldb-module-in-python)

So combining it with your code:

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM rolodex WHERE rolodex_id = " + rolodex_id
default_value = None
cursor = mdb_connect("DictCursor")
cursor.execute(sql)
row = cursor.fetchone()
row = [value for value in row if value else default_value]
form = RolodexEntry(*row)
return bottle.template('entry',rolodex_id=rolodex_id,form=form)
```

and as your default you'd have `None` instead of the empty string;

```
firstname  = TextField('First Name',[validators.length(max=40)], default=None)
```

Is that helpful at all?

Comment: hi -  Thanks for your response, but I'm not following how this helps.  In my case, the database contains both empty and NULL fields (i.e. some of the database fields are already set to "").  In either case, `form.field_name.data` prints out as `None` in the resulting HTML page (i.e. the characters N-o-n-e).  From this it seems clear that any false value in `row` will print out as `None`.  Since I want it to default to just leaving the field blank if the value from the database is `False`, presetting the field value in the dictionary doesn't help (see following comment).

Comment: In fact, if I explicitly set one of the fields to be "" (i.e. blank string):  `row['cellphone'] = ""` before passing it to the form: `form = RolodexEntry(**row)`  it still prints out as `None` in the HTML file.  What I don't understand is why this isn't addressed by the `default` field attribute.

Comment: As an experiment - what happens when you do the same again (set `row['cellphone']=''`) but set `firstname  = TextField('First Name',[validators.length(max=40)], default="Test string")` and see what is displayed. This will check if `default` is handling it. I just want to see if it's treating the empty string as `None` or a  string.

Comment: `default` doesn't appear to do anything.  Here is my field definition: `cell = TextField('Cellphone', [validators.length(max=25)], filters=[strip_filter], default="Test String")`  I explicitly set `row['cell'] = ""` just prior to passing the dictionary to the form.  What shows up in the HTML for this template variable: `<td>{{form.cell.data}}</td>` is `None`

Comment: The strip_filter filter I was using: `strip_filter = lambda x: x.strip() if x else None` was responsible for the `None` I was seeing in the HTML.  Changing this to `strip_filter = lambda x: x.strip() if x else ""` solves my problem.  However, `default` is still being ignored, as far as I can tell.  If I change my field definition to `cell = TextField('Cellphone', default= "Text Field")` with everything else the same, the HTML now shows up with no cell information `<td></td>`  -- not `Text Field`

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurred to me today, but I use Flask_WTF, so my syntax is different. My solution was solved by adding `Optional()` to my `validators[]` list.

```
address_zip_extension = StringField('address_zip_extension', render_kw={"placeholder": "Zip Extension", "section": "address",
                                    'label': 'Zip Extension'}, validators=[Optional(), Length(min=4, max=5)])
```

For the normal WTForms, the syntax is different, but I believe that something like the following should work.

```
class MyForm(Form):
    name = TextField('Name', [Optional(), my_length_check])
```

Good luck!